# How to predict if a phrase is related to a short text or an article using supervised learning?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I have set of short phrases and a set of texts. I want to predict if a phrase is related to an article. A phrase that isn't appearing in the article may still be related.

Some examples of annotated data (not real) is like this:

Example 1

> **Phrase:**  Automobile
>
> **Text:** Among the more affordable options in the electric-vehicle marketplace, the 2021 Tesla Model 3 is without doubt the one with the
> most name recognition. It borrows some styling cues from the company's
> Model S sedan and Model X SUV, but goes its own way with a unique
> interior design and an all-glass roof. Acceleration is quick, and the
> Model 3's chassis is playful as well—especially the Performance
> model's, which receives a sportier suspension and a track driving
> mode. But EV buyers are more likely interested in driving range than
> speediness or handling, and the Model 3 delivers there too. The base
> model offers up to 263 miles of driving range according to the EPA,
> and the more expensive Long Range model can go up to 353 per charge.
>
> **Label:** Related (PS: For a given text, one and only one phrase is labeled 'Related' with it. All others are 'Unrelated')

Example 2

> **Phrase:** Programming languages
>
> **Text:** Python 3.9 uses a new parser, based on PEG instead of LL(1). The new parser’s performance is roughly comparable to that of the old
> parser, but the PEG formalism is more flexible than LL(1) when it
> comes to designing new language features. We’ll start using this
> flexibility in Python 3.10 and later.
>
> The ast module uses the new parser and produces the same AST as the
> old parser.
>
> In Python 3.10, the old parser will be deleted and so will all
> functionality that depends on it (primarily the parser module, which
> has long been deprecated). In Python 3.9 only, you can switch back to
> the LL(1) parser using a command line switch (-X oldparser) or an
> environment variable (PYTHONOLDPARSER=1).
>
> **Label:** Related(i.e. all other phrases are 'Unrelated')

I think I may have to use, for example, pre-trained BERT, because this kind of prediction needs additional knowledge. But this does not seem like a standard classification problem so I can't find out-of-the-box codes. May I have some advice on how to combine existing wheels and train it?

Comment: This does look like a typical text classification problem. Do you have a training data set or want to use a pre-trained model? For your second data example, what if the phrases to check were "programming languages" and "programming"? You are still expecting only one to be related?

Comment: An article may not strictly related to only one phrase, but mostly. 

In real data, the phrases are non-overlapping technical fields and I want to check if one article belongs to that field. 

But I can not regard the phrases as labels and perform a direct classification, because the training set has only a small portion of phrases. It will meet unknown new phrases when doing prediction. 

So I want the phrases not only be just label numbers to the model. The model should read the phrase and guess its meaning to perform classification.

Comment: Is the list of phrases to check "relatedness" against fixed?

Comment: Not fixed. I don't have a full list of the phrases.

Comment: Your best bet then is zero shot learning with HuggingFace transformers if you can use Python - https://joeddav.github.io/blog/2020/05/29/ZSL.html. If it helps, let me know and I will convert this to an answer

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.

Comment: OK - I will convert to answer with more detail in the next couple of days and please accept it